# Google in Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, internet

Google search and youtube do not work in Chrome on Linux (Ubutu 12.04 x64, Mint 14 x64, Android on Nexus 7). I can find video on youtube, but it don't loading. Also, i can get results from google search, but can't open links. When i use Firefox - all right. On Win7 x64 works fine too. 
P.S. Lenovo Y570, wi-fi router -> dls.

Comment: what do you mean 'do not work' in Chrome?

Comment: You have basically not provided *any* detail to help us solve your problem. I appreciate that it's not easy being a noob, but you'll need to either supply more information or find someone a bit more able with computers to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open links? Seems to me like you have some kind of odd extension/malware. About the youtube problem: what version of flash are you using?